# Eliminate duplicates from hashmap list and count their support

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a list of `itemMap` (`Map<ArrayList<String>, Integer> itemMap = new HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Integer>()` )
containing the following elments

```
 { [File3, File2]=4, 
   [File2, File3]=2, 
   [File1, File2]=6,
   [File1, File3]=2, 
   [File3, File1]=6,
   [File2, File1]=6 }
```

I want to obtain a list containing no duplicates. (in my case a duplicate is a list containing same elements of another list).Example (F1,F2) and (F2,F1) are the same in my work.

So I want to obtain the following result:

```
{ [File3, File2]=6, 
  [File1, File3]=8, 
  [File1, File2]=12 }
```

As you see I sum the counts of duplicates but I keep one of the duplicates in my hashmap.
Can anybody help me with a simple code and thank you.
My own try was a fail:

```
HashMap<List<String>,Integer>   myobjectListB  = new HashMap<List<String>,Integer>();
        for (List <String> key : itemMap.keySet()){
            for (List <String> y : itemMap.keySet()){
            if((key.containsAll(y) && (!key.equals(y))) && (key.size())==y.size()) {
                int count = itemMap.get(key)+itemMap.get(y);
                myobjectListB.put(key, count);


            }   

            }

        }
        System.out.println("object list"+ myobjectListB);

    }
```

Comment: I did my own try but it was wrong, i edited the post, I put my try in it.

Comment: A list containing no duplicate is usually called a set.  Did you try with HashSet or LinkedHashSet if order matters ?

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `ArrayList` with a `HashSet` it will work the way you intend it to. That's because the `Map` interface only stores one value per key, and it determines if two keys are equal using the `equals` method. Two `ArrayList`s containing the same objects in different order will return `false` when compared, but two `HashSet`s containing the same objects in different order will return `true`

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a method where you get a new map without duplicates. When you add values to the new map, it always check if the list contains in the `keyset` and also check the swapped list is also contains in the `keyset`. So there won't be any duplicates.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<ArrayList<String>, Integer> itemMap = new HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Integer>();
        itemMap.put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("File3", "File2")), 4);
        itemMap.put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("File2", "File3")), 2);
        itemMap.put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("File1", "File2")), 6);
        itemMap.put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("File1", "File3")), 2);
        itemMap.put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("File3", "File1")), 6);
        itemMap.put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("File2", "File1")), 6);

        System.out.println(removeDuplicates(itemMap));
    }

    static Map<ArrayList<String>, Integer> removeDuplicates(Map<ArrayList<String>, Integer> map) {
        Map<ArrayList<String>, Integer> convertedMap = new HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Integer>();

        for (ArrayList<String> list : map.keySet()) {
            if (!convertedMap.keySet().contains(list)) {
                Collections.swap(list, 0, 1);
                if (!convertedMap.keySet().contains(list)) {
                    convertedMap.put(list, map.get(list));
                }
            }
        }
        return convertedMap;

    }
}
```